# Trying to import a Pandas table in a GUI

Tags: python, pandas, pysimplegui

I am trying to import a pandas table in a GUI, but it seems that to place headings into both the x and y axis (Desired result is in the table). Any suggestions?

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = Output

headings = ['Result', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'D-level', 'R-level', 'n_matches', 'nan', 'nonnan', 'Match_Acc.']

layout = [[sg.Table(Output, headings=headings, justification='left', key='-TABLE-')],]
window = sg.Window("Overview", layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

| Result | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | D-level | R-level | n_matches | nan | nonnan | Match_Acc. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FRA | Paris | pytesseract | rowwords | 1 | 4.0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 33.333333 |

Answer (score 2):

Using method `to_list` to convert dataframe to a list.

```py
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ('Courier New', 11)
sg.set_options(font=font)

data = {
    'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
    'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

headings = df.columns.tolist()
data = df.values.tolist()

layout = [[sg.Table(data, headings=headings, justification='left', key='-TABLE-')],]
sg.Window("Overview", layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however this does still not put the data from my Pandas table into the GUI. I have updated to post the reflect what I want in there.

Comment: You can use method `to_list` to convert a dataframe to a list to as the headings and data of the Table element.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks man. That solved it!